# Maximum Flow Generic Push Relabel Algorithm Time Complexity for Saturating Push

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, max-flow

I checked the algorithm here **Introduction to algorithms third edition page 747** (http://kddlab.zjgsu.edu.cn:7200/students/lipengcheng/%E7%AE%97%E6%B3%95%E5%AF%BC%E8%AE%BA%EF%BC%88%E8%8B%B1%E6%96%87%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%89%E7%89%88%EF%BC%89.pdf)

By Corollary 26.25, saturating push operation can be done in O(1).
But how to achieve O(1)?

I think at least I need O(V) to search (u, v) possible to Push(u, v).
What data structure can be used to do the operation in O(1)?

Answer (score 0):

The *push* operation itself as described on page 739 clearly works in *O*(1) because it contains no loops. Additionally, we need an *O*(1) way to find an applicable operation to execute (push or relabel), as Corollary 26.25 claims. This is achieved in the next section, the relabel-to-front algorithm. Please see the *relabel-to-front* pseudocode on page 755 and the *discharge* pseudocode on page 751.